# how to stop deployment if config load fails

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

On deployment of my war file I load config into a singleton from the database.
If any of the required config variables are missing in the database, I want the application to halt.

In Java I would do System.exit(1), but if I understand correctly this will kill the JVM, which is glassfish.

How do I kill the application?

Answer (score 1):

Override the [Servlet.init](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#init%28javax.servlet.ServletConfig%29) method of your Servlet:

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
   super.init(ServletConfig); 

//load config from database, and eventually launch an exception of type ServletException
// for example throw new RequiredConfigMissingException(...);
}
```

and launch an exception of type ServletException (it is better if you extends it) in case of required config missing:

```
public class RequiredConfigMissingException extends ServletException
```

The Application Server will not load your web application and stop the deployment writing the error on the app server log.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a servlet, but a web service. Not sure if there is something similar?

Comment: I think he means that you have to do it in the startup servlet. if you don't have a startup servlet, create a servlet and set it as a startup servlet in your web.xml

Comment: can you post the web.xml file for you web context?

Comment: I'm asking because your web app will have a servlet configured, maybe a third party servlet, so what you can do is simply 'decorate' that server: extend it and override init and call your new servlet from web.config instead of the old one

Comment: I'm using netbeans to generate the webservice. There is no web.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get the required result by throwing a ExceptionInInitializerError.
Since the exception occurs inside the @PostConstruct method of the @Startup singleton it stops the deployment.

I will look into the web.xml file. 
Thanks for all the help.